# UCAP connection in atmega 32u4

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmel, cad

What connection does UCAP have in atmega 32u4? I heard that a capacitor should be connected. Could someone give me more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find this information in the [device datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf) found on [www.atmel.com](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega32u4.aspx?tab=documents)

> 2.2.12 UCAP USB Pads Internal Regulator Output supply voltage. Should be connected to an external capacitor (1µF).